# Copying files from directory structure with a wildcard in the path

Tags: xcopy

This seems extremely simple, but I somehow can't get it to work, so hoping you guys can help.

I have a very large Winforms solution that i'm trying to extract all dll's following a build. My build pushes all dll's into a folder within each project during the build, so that I end up with a similar file structure.

Structure would be like this but with varying project names:
C:\solution\project1\bin
C:\solution\project2\bin
C:\solution\project3\bin

I thought it would be really easy to run an xcopy command like below to copy to a single location, but i'm not sure how to use a wildcard in the path:
xcopy C:\solution\???\bin\*.dll C:\Output

Is this possible with xcopy? If not, any other suggestions, maybe powershell?

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Powershell Solution:

```
$srcPath  = "C:\mySource"
$destPath = "C:\myDest"

# Generate List of files with the .dll extension in $srcPath
$fileList = (Get-ChildItem -Path $srcPath | Where-Object {$_.Extension -eq     ".dll"}).FullName

# Copies files to new destination $destPath
foreach ($file in $fileList){
    Move-Item -Path $file -Destination $destPath
}
```

Just replace the $srcPath and $destPath variables with the desired locations.